# possible to make sections in theme customizer sortable and saveable at publish button clicked?

Tags: jquery, theme-customizer, jquery-ui, options

We do have kirki(a theme customizer toolkit) `sortable field`. But i want to apply the same logic on the sections itself instead of creating another section with sortable fields.
 I'm using options instead of theme mods, just for better visualization right now.
 The things i tried so far:
 in `functions.php` I have this code below to create an option row in option table:

```
$sortable_sections = get_option('sortable_sections');
  if(!isset($sortable_sections) OR empty($sortable_sections)){
  add_option('sortable_sections', array('eat', 'pray','love'));
}
```

The code to create sections in a file named `kirki-config.php` which is required in `functions.php` as below

```
$sortable_sections = get_option('sortable_sections');
foreach($sortable_sections as $sortable_section){
 Kirki::add_section( $sortable_section, array(
    'title'          => esc_attr__( strtoupper($sortable_section), 'airspace' ),
    'description'    => esc_attr__( 'Insert content', 'airspace' ),
    'panel'          => 'frontpage_panel',
) );
}
```

the above code creates three sections with id eat, pray, love respectively.

the code in `js` is as below:(file hooked to `admin_enqueue_scripts`)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

  $('#sub-accordion-panel-frontpage_panel').sortable({
    items: '.control-section-kirki-default',
    axis : 'y',
    cursor: 'move,
   update: function(){
      //here i want the code which gets the updated reordered array and passed to a  
      //php file using .sortable('serialize'), only after clicking the publish
     // button. the problem is the publish button is disabled even after
    // sections got new positions.
   }
  });
});
```

and in php file i want code something like as below:

```
$new_array = $_POST['accordion-section'];
update_option('sortable_sections', $new_array);
```

So there are two steps which i'm having problem to finish.
1. enabling and disabling the publish button
2.after clicking the button js variable goes to php file and updates the option.

How to achieve it, and is there any better method to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with creating sortable sections in customizer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308100/problems-with-creating-sortable-sections-in-customizer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple tutorial - How to sort customizer sections in the panel and add order to theme.

**1.** You must use prefixes to do this because customizer don't support custom classes.

- `ctmss_panel_` - for panels
- `ctmss_section_` - for sections
- `ctmss_hidden_` - for hidden sections that has a input with values

**2.** Add panel to the Customizer - [add_panel()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_panel/)

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'ctmss_panel_panelname1', array(
    'title'    => esc_html__( 'My Panel', 'textdomain' ),
    'priority' => 150
) );
```

**3.** Add section with text input to save new sections order. Hide this section with CSS. [add_section()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_section/), [add_setting()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/), [add_control()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_control/)

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'ctmss_hidden_sectionname1', array(
    'title'       => esc_html__( 'Section hidden', 'textdomain' ),
    'panel'       => 'ctmss_panel_panelname1',
    'priority'    => 1
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'ctmss_sections_order', array(
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'sections_order',
        array(
            'settings' => 'ctmss_sections_order',
            'type'     => 'text',
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Section layout', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'ctmss_hidden_sectionname1',
        )
    )
);
```

**4.** Create array() with available sections. If saved values is available get it, else set default sections and order.

```
$default_sections = array (
    'ctmss_section_sectionname1' => array (
        'title'       => esc_html__( 'Section 1', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => esc_html__( 'Section 1 Description', 'textdomain' ),
    ),
    'ctmss_section_sectionname2' => array (
        'title'       => esc_html__( 'Section 2', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => esc_html__( 'Section 2 Description', 'textdomain' ),
    ),
    'ctmss_section_sectionname3' => array (
        'title'       => esc_html__( 'Section 3', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => esc_html__( 'Section 3 Description', 'textdomain' ),
    ),
    'ctmss_section_sectionname4' => array (
        'title'       => esc_html__( 'Section 4', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => esc_html__( 'Section 4 Description', 'textdomain' ),
    ),
);

$sortable_sections = get_theme_mod('ctmss_sections_order');
if( !isset( $sortable_sections ) || empty( $sortable_sections ) ){
    set_theme_mod( 'ctmss_sections_order', implode(',', array_keys( $default_sections ) ) );
}
$sortable_sections = explode(',', $sortable_sections );

foreach( $sortable_sections as $sortable_section ){
    $wp_customize->add_section( $sortable_section, array(
        'title'       => $default_sections[$sortable_section]['title'],
        'description' => $default_sections[$sortable_section]['description'],
        'panel'       => 'ctmss_panel_panelname1'
    ) );
}
```

**5.** Add controls to the sections. Example:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'myprefix_section1_layout', array(
        'default'           => 'classic',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'section1_layout',
        array(
            'settings' => 'myprefix_section1_layout',
            'type'     => 'radio',
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Section layout', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'ctmss_section_sectionname1',
            'choices'  => array(
                'classic'          => esc_html__( 'Classic', 'textdomain' ),
                'grid'             => esc_html__( 'Grid', 'textdomain' ),
                'list'             => esc_html__( 'List', 'textdomain' ),
            )
        )
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'myprefix_section2_layout', array(
        'default'           => 'classic',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'section2_layout',
        array(
            'settings' => 'myprefix_section2_layout',
            'type'     => 'radio',
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Section layout', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'ctmss_section_sectionname2',
            'choices'  => array(
                'classic'          => esc_html__( 'Classic', 'textdomain' ),
                'grid'             => esc_html__( 'Grid', 'textdomain' ),
                'list'             => esc_html__( 'List', 'textdomain' ),
            )
        )
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'myprefix_section3_layout', array(
        'default'           => 'classic',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'section3_layout',
        array(
            'settings' => 'myprefix_section3_layout',
            'type'     => 'radio',
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Section layout', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'ctmss_section_sectionname3',
            'choices'  => array(
                'classic'          => esc_html__( 'Classic', 'textdomain' ),
                'grid'             => esc_html__( 'Grid', 'textdomain' ),
                'list'             => esc_html__( 'List', 'textdomain' ),
            )
        )
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'myprefix_section4_layout', array(
        'default'           => 'classic',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'section4_layout',
        array(
            'settings' => 'myprefix_section4_layout',
            'type'     => 'radio',
            'label'    => esc_html__( 'Section layout', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'ctmss_section_sectionname4',
            'choices'  => array(
                'classic'          => esc_html__( 'Classic', 'textdomain' ),
                'grid'             => esc_html__( 'Grid', 'textdomain' ),
                'list'             => esc_html__( 'List', 'textdomain' ),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**6.** Add styles and scripts.

```
function my_customizer_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_customizer_js', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/my-customizer.js', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
}
add_action('customize_controls_print_scripts', 'my_customizer_scripts');

function my_customizer_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_customizer_css', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/css/my-customizer.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
}
add_action('customize_controls_print_styles', 'my_customizer_styles');
```

my-customizer.css

```
li[id*="ctmss_hidden_"],
ul[id*="ctmss_hidden_"],
.ctmss_hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

.ctmss_section .accordion-section-title:active {
    cursor: move !important;
}
```

my-customizer.js

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

    $('ul[id*="ctmss_panel_"]').addClass('ctmss_panel');
    $('ul.ctmss_panel').each( function() {
        if( 0 === $(this).length ){
            return true;
        }

        var panel = $(this),
            panelSectionHidden = panel.find('li[id*="ctmss_hidden_"]').attr('aria-owns');

        panel.find('li[id*="ctmss_section_"]').addClass('ctmss_section');
        panel.find('li[id*="ctmss_hidden_"]').addClass('ctmss_hidden');

        // Init sortable.
        panel.sortable( {
            item: 'li.ctmss_section',
            axis: 'y',

            // Update value when we stop sorting.
            stop: function() {
                updateValue();
            }
        });

        // Updates the sorting list.
        function updateValue() {
            var inputValues = panel.find( '.ctmss_section' ).map( function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id'),
                    id = id.replace('accordion-section-','');

                return id;
            }).get().join(',');

            // Add the value to the hidden field
            $( '#' + panelSectionHidden ).find( '.customize-control-text input' ).prop( 'value', inputValues );

            // Important! Make sure to trigger change event so Customizer knows it has to save the field
            $( '#' + panelSectionHidden ).find( '.customize-control-text input' ).trigger('change');

            console.log( inputValues );
        }

    });

});
```

**7.** Add function to display sections.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'ctmss_get_sections' ) ):
    function ctmss_get_sections( $sections ) {

        $sections = explode(',', $sections);

        $output = '';

        if ( empty( $sections ) ) {
            return $output;
        }

        foreach( $sections as $section ) {

            switch ( $section ) {

            case 'ctmss_section_sectionname1':
                $output .= '<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; padding: 40px; background: #e1e1e1;">Section 1</div>';
                break;

            case 'ctmss_section_sectionname2':
                $output .= '<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; padding: 40px; background: #e3e3e3;">Section 2</div>';
                break;

            case 'ctmss_section_sectionname3':
                $output .= '<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; padding: 40px; background: #e5e5e5;">Section 3</div>';
                break;

            case 'ctmss_section_sectionname4':
                $output .= '<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; padding: 40px; background: #e7e7e7;">Section 4</div>';
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        return $output;

    }
endif;
```

**8.** Run your code where you want.

```
echo ctmss_get_sections( get_theme_mod('ctmss_sections_order') );
```

This solution works without Kirki but is easy to customize it.

Comment: jquery .sortable('serialize') does all the heavy  lifting, it gives you an array with new order, so  we can use `update: function(){ $('#publish_button').sortable('serialize');    }` the problem is publish button only gets activated upon changes the value of the controller only. So what i want is 1. activate publish button upon sections positions changes 2. upon clicking database updates, page refreshes and then the button gets deactivated again and the sections get the new order

Comment: @seeker I updated my answer. You must create hidden field in panel with an array of sections and for save new values.

Comment: ok, how the database interaction going to work and how the new order going to be saved?

Comment: When hidden field will be changed then you can save values Publish button will be enabled. New order can be saved as array or comma-separated list - use `.join(", ")`.To get values you can use `get_theme_mod()`. Updated answear.

Comment: as in step one you mentioned i need to create a hidden input field, you mean i need to create a new section with a hidden input field and then hide that new section with css, right?

Comment: You can create this hidden input field where you want.
If you have a section with hidden input field ( for sections order ) in panel that has a sortable sections you must remember to remove the hidden section in JS.

Comment: one problem having with the code, if i click the publish button the sections going back to previous order, but the database getting updated, cause if i refresh the page, sections are getting the new sorted order. Can you please take a look the whole process? thank you

Comment: You need sections order in your theme files ? For example - sections on home page ?

Comment: in wordpress theme customizer. and yes i'm building a theme, not a plugin.

Comment: @seeker Added small tutorial.

Comment: I am trying to order the sections of the theme home page located in a dedicated panel. Do you have a demo or a short video of the customizer showing how this implementation behaves?